# Add another level - side menu HTML/Boostrap 3/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I add another level to this menu structure from the HTML at the bottom of the page?

Current

```
Test

--->a
--->b
```

what I'm trying to do

```
Test

   --->a
           --->1
           --->2
   --->b
           --->1
           --->2
```

html

```
<li class="nav-header">
    <a data-target="#menu5" data-toggle="collapse" href="#">
    <h3>test</h3></a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled collapse" id="menu5">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle"></i> Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle"></i> Twitter</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/QutOBjvgha

Comment: ??? that doesn't seem to be what im looking for

Comment: The examples [on the Bootstrap 3 website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) show a multi-level menu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-header">
                <a data-target="#menu5" data-toggle="collapse" href="#">
                <h3>test</h3></a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled collapse" id="menu5">
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#submenu" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle"></i> Facebook</a>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled collapse" id="submenu">
                           <li> 1 </li>
                           <li> 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle"></i> Twitter</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I believe you just need to create another collapse element with a unique Id. using the `<a>` element as your toggle.